# Tapping or clicking sound coming from the floor... when central air conditioning or heating comes on?

Tags: hvac

What causes a ticking sound coming from the floor when the central air conditioning or heating comes on?

Comment: loose flap from multi-zone valve

Answer (score 14):

Most likely what you are hearing is thermal expansion or contraction of ducting and associate metal brackets and supports.

Unless it is very very loud or very cyclic and it carries on all the time the unit is on, this is normal.