# How to mitigate thermal expansion clicking in ductwork?

Tags: hvac, sound-proofing, sound-deadening

[This recent answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/295686/146957) identifies a common source of clicking and tapping sounds: thermal expansion and contraction of ductwork and brackets.

While it's true that this is perfectly normal, it's also annoying. What are some ways to mitigate these sounds? Different material for ducts? Different bracket types?

Comment: Most such mitigation is only practical at original installation time - Doing things like providing a slippery plastic or felt bearing material between brackets and ducts (some older installs, particularly baseboard hot water, used lead between pipes and brackets - not so popular these days. Those, at least, are mostly accessible for retrofitting. Ducts tend to be inaccessible once the building is built.)

Comment: The type of ducting you have will help.  Where the tapping/clicking comes from will help also.  Tapping/clicking sounds almost from the burn chamber of a furnace when the metal cools, but thin metal sheet duct work usually sounds like bangs as it expands/contracts.  Might just be loose hangers.

Comment: Don't run the HVAC?